# Contradiction of the entropy of a compound system?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, electrical-resistance

Let's say we have a tank of oil and a resistance inside it. We let a current flow through the resistance and we are going to study the change of the entropy of the resistance or of the universe.

What I thought is that since no work is being applied, $Q_{resistance}=0$ and hence $$\Delta S_{resistance}=0$$ Which is fine so far it seems (although wouldn't this be true only if the process is reversible?). But in order to find the change of entropy of the oil, wouldn't it also be 0, since the heat of the resistance is the one that the tank the oil receives and so on, such that we would get $Q_{resistance}+Q_{oil}=0\Rightarrow Q_{oil}=0$ and then once again we find that $$\Delta S_{oil}=0$$ but then again, this isn't any reversible process, so the change of the entropy shouldn't be $0$, it should be more than $0$, but however, if we calculate it, we find that $$\Delta S_{universe}=\Delta S_{oil}+\Delta S_{resistance}=0+0=0$$ What is going on? I'm guessing we can't just broadly assume $dS=\frac{dQ}{T}$, but then how else am I supposed to find those entropies?

Comment: How are you able to state that no work implies $Q = 0$ when $Q$ is heat? Are you forgetting to analyze the system using the first law before you even apply the second law definition of entropy?

Comment: All that electrical power that could have done some real work is ending up as useless heat...

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer I've always thought a resistance can't apply heat, I thought it only has disipative work to it that is $W=R^2 It$, and by the 0th principle, the heat that one gives is the same (negative) that the other receives. What's wrong with that reasoning? Or else can someone tell me how would I find the entropy on those cases?

Comment: How do electric heaters actually give off heat then? The zero law of thermodynamics is that temperatures are equivalent, not that heat flow is equivalent. Finally, we are telling you to apply the first law before applying the second law (again ... how do electric heaters "work" to give off heat?).

Comment: @Ulshy have a try and touch an incandescent bulb light, that is nothing more than an electric resistor. It becomes very hot (such an non-efficient way to produce light...) and "hot bodies transfer heat to cold bodies" (your hand). Do not touch it, just put your hand close to the bulb

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense

Answer (score 1):

The tank–resistor system as a whole is not undergoing thermodynamic heating, defined as energy transfer driven by a temperature difference. Therefore, the equation $\Delta S=\frac{Q}{T}$ (which refers to the entropy transfer when the surroundings heat a system at temperature $T$ via energy transfer $Q$) is not immediately useful.

Put another way, no entropy enters this system; electrical work carries no entropy.

Instead, entropy is being generated inside the system through the irreversible process of Joule heating.

How much entropy?

Since entropy is a state variable, we are free to replace this irreversible process with a reversible one that begins and ends at matching conditions. Let's choose reversible heating with total energy transfer $I^2Rt$, with current $I$, resistance $R$, and time $t$ matching those values from the irreversible case. The rate of entropy increase in the tank–resistor system is then $\frac{dS}{dt}=\frac{I^2R}{T}$, and the total entropy increase is thus $\Delta S\approx\frac{I^2Rt}{T}$ if the heat capacity of the system is large enough relative to the dissipated energy that the temperature change is minimal. This is also the entropy increase of the universe in the irreversible case.